# Searching the content of one file using the search key from another file

Tags: shell, scripting, grep

I have two files:
file 1:

```
hello.com   neo.com,japan.com,example.com
news.net    xyz.com, telecom.net, highlands.net, software.com
example2.com    earth.net, abc.gov.uk
```

file 2:

```
neo.com
example.com
abc.gov.uk
```

file 2 are the search keys to search in file 1 if any of the search key is found in file 1 it should return the line of file 1 with search keys or  else just the row of the file 1 like this:

```
hello.com    neo.com, example.com 
news.net     
example2.com    abc.gov.uk
```

I tried this:

```
grep -F -f file2 file1
```

The result I got is this

```
hello.com   neo.com,japan.com,example.com
example2.com    earth.net, abc.gov.uk
```

but I am not able to get the else part of the test. Any suggestion to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

if it is required to keep the initial order, this awk one liner could help:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}
     {l=$1;for(x in a)if($0~a[x]){l=$0;break}print l}' file2 file1
```

with the test data, it outputs:

```
hello.com   neo.com,japan.com,example.com
news.net
example2.com    earth.net, abc.gov.uk
```

Note that there could be a problem, I did regex match check in the one-liner, if in your file2 things are domains, you can escape the `.(dot)` before adding them into the array `a[NR]`

Comment: it worked amazingly but just another concern how to tune the awk code above if in case I need to retrieve the test data that has a match with the search data for instance:

Comment: the comment was messed up above :-(  I want to retrieve row that has a match with the search key for instance hello.com    neo.com example.com and not the others  that are not in the search key if no match I want to retrieve the column in the above case like news.net

Comment: @MohanTimilsina try changing `l=$0` into `sub(/^[^ ]* +/,"");l=$0`

Comment: I tried this: awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}
     {l=$1;for(x in a)if($0~a[x]){sub(/^[^ ]* +/,"");l=$0;break}print l}'  and still japan.com is showed in the first row since it is not in the search key also example2.com is not showed but abc.gov.uk is shown but I need example2.com  abc.gov.uk also

Comment: @MohanTimilsina I thought you want that value. can you edit your question, give input and output? there you can control the format better.

Comment: I improved my output in the question.

Comment: @MohanTimilsina nice... you didn't append the new requirement, just modified the old, this made my answer fail. ... Okay. FYI, to get your new requirement, you need loop from `$2` to the end `$NF`, check matching, and output each matched field, when you output, use `printf` to avoid the new line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shell scripting to get the required result

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r lineA <&3 read -r lineB <&4
do
   line=`echo "$lineA" | grep "$lineB"`
   if [ -n "$line" ] ; then
     echo "$lineA";
   else
     echo `echo $lineA | sed 's/\([^ ]*\).*/\1/g'`
   fi
done 3<1.txt 4<2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
 fgrep -f file2 file1
 fgrep -v -f file2 file1 | sed 's/ .*//'
}
```

first (f)grep take info that contain the reference, the second take the other and sed change the content. I just group the actions to allow a sort or other post action on the whole result